# How do I load JSON-encoded data from the server to my page?

Tags: json

I am using jQuery EasyUI to create a [checkbox tree](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=Tree&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=). I tried their demos, and it works great locally. When I tried it on the server, I do not see the tree list.

I included the necessary js files:
 - jquery-1.6.1.min.js
 - jquery.easyui.min.js

Here is the html:

```
    <ul id="tt" class="easyui-tree"
        url="data/tree_data.json"
        checkbox="true">
</ul>
```

Here is the JSON data:

```
    [{
    "id":1,
    "text":"Fruits",
    "state":"closed",
    "children":[{
        "text":"Apple"
    },{
        "text":"Pear"
    }]
}]
```

How can I get the json data to load on my page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
data = $.parseJSON(var);
alert(data.id);
```

where var contains your json data.

Comment: @kmatyaszek Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I added: method="get" and that worked fine. but now IE8 cannot expand/collapse the tree.

<ul id="tt" class="easyui-tree"
        url="data/tree_data.json"
        checkbox="true"
        method="get">
</ul>